# Copying Specific File from Zip Files VBA

Tags: vba, excel, zip

I am trying to copy specific file from zip files. The following code running succesfully but it not copy the file from zip to Folder.

Any suggestion would be appreciated..

```
 Sub Unzip5()
        Dim FSO As Object
        Dim oApp As Object
        Dim Fname As Variant
        Dim FileNameFolder As Variant
        Dim DefPath As String
        Dim strDate As String
        Dim I As Long
        Dim num As Long

        Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Zip Files (*.zip), *.zip", _
                                            MultiSelect:=True)
        If IsArray(Fname) = False Then
            'Do nothing
        Else

            FileNameFolder = "D:\Template\test\"



            Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

          For I = LBound(Fname) To UBound(Fname)
                num = oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).Items.Count
                        For Each fileNameInZip In oApp.Namespace(Fname(I)).Items
                                    If fileNameInZip Like "repo*" Then
                                        oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname(I)).Items.Item(CStr(fileNameInZip)) 
'this above line working fine but not copying file from zip
                                        Exit For
                                    End If
                                Next
                'oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname(I)).Items

            Next I

            MsgBox "You find the files here: " & FileNameFolder

            On Error Resume Next
            Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
            FSO.deletefolder Environ("Temp") & "\Temporary Directory*", True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing that problem because `CStr(fileNameInZip)` is giving you the file name without the extention.

Replace `CStr(fileNameInZip)` by `GetFilenameFromPath(fileNameInZip.Path)`

and add the below function

```
Private Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
    If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
        GetFilenameFromPath = _
        GetFilenameFromPath(Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Now try it :)

So your code looks like this

```
Sub Unzip5()
        Dim FSO As Object, oApp As Object
        Dim Fname As Variant, FileNameFolder As Variant
        Dim DefPath As String, strDate As String
        Dim I As Long, num As Long

        Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Zip Files (*.zip), *.zip", _
                                            MultiSelect:=True)
        If IsArray(Fname) = True Then
            FileNameFolder = "D:\Template\test\"

            Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

            For I = LBound(Fname) To UBound(Fname)
                num = oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).Items.Count

                For Each fileNameInZip In oApp.Namespace(Fname(I)).Items
                    If fileNameInZip Like "repo*" Then
                        oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere _
                        oApp.Namespace(Fname(I)).Items.Item(GetFilenameFromPath(fileNameInZip.Path))

                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Next I

            MsgBox "You find the files here: " & FileNameFolder

            On Error Resume Next
            Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
            FSO.deletefolder Environ("Temp") & "\Temporary Directory*", True
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
        If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
            GetFilenameFromPath = _
            GetFilenameFromPath(Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
        End If
    End Function
```